# Коммерческое использование Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, юридические-аспекты

Можно ли писать коммерческие приложения на Visual Studio 2015 Community? В команде 2 человека, продукт не связан с банковскими и финансовыми API скорее система учета. Продукт на продажу третьим лицам. Имеет ли значение число покупателей? Обязательно ли покупать лицензию Proffessional для продажи своего ПО? Сам не юрист, поэтому прошу помощи тех кто уже продавал свой софт.

Comment: [_Индивидуальная лицензия. Если вы являетесь физическим лицом, разрабатывающим собственные приложения для продажи или с какой-либо другой целью, вы можете использовать данное программное обеспечение для разработки и тестирования таких приложений._](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/license-terms/mt171547/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fcompany%2Fmicrosoft%2Fblog%2F271813%2F)

Comment: @Grundy а если я просто сотрудник компании, индивидуальная лицензия не распространяется же.

Comment: Там после приведенного пункта, есть пункты как раз для компаний

Answer (score 1):

Почитав условия лицензии, присланной уважаемым @Grundy и поговорив со знакомыми юристами, было найдено простое решение : 
Если проект разрабатывается фирмой(юридическим лицом) на VS 2015 Community с открытым исходным кодом то платная лицензия не требуется. Для индивидуального разработчика, даже Open Source не обязателен.